# In search of some embedded processor

Tags: embedded, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project involving the following with my team:

1. GUI and a keyboard for user interaction.
2. Real-time processing and display.
3. SPI communication.
4. USB-based printing.

1, 2 and 3 are to be done in parallel.

Currently we are using Raspberry Pi. But R-pi is lagging in doing the job. So any other embedded processor meeting the above specs and should be less than $100.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

PS: Do ask questions if I'm vague in my statements.

Comment: Sourcing questions aren't really viewed as on-topic on the stack exchange sites, but your price range should include many possibilities - the beagle family, some smaller PC motherboards, etc.  Also consider that you may do better to concentrate on efficiency of implementation rather than just raw horsepower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the beaglebone black.  Its 1GHz processor should be more then sufficient to do your processing.  Also it is ARM7, Ubuntu dropped support for ARM6 (Pi) a couple of months ago.

http://beagleboard.org/products/beaglebone%20black

Answer (score 2):

Your lack of real-time response probably has more to do with the fact that Linux is not a real-time OS than the performance of the RPi.  You can throw processing power at the problem if you like, but it still may not reliable solve your problem.

It is not possible to advise based on the little information you have provided; you'd need to define the real-time response requirements in terms of time and quantity of data to be processed.

While an RTOS might solve your real-time processing problems, that would need you needing drivers for the USB printer, display, and a GUI implementation, these are readily available for Linux, but not so much for a typical low-cost RTOS, especially a USB printer driver, since the raster-image processing required is complex and resource hungry - resources a typical Linux system will have.

If you have the necessary time and skill, you could port RTLinux to RPi (or some other board capable of supporting Linux).  It has a different scheduler to the standard time-sharing kernel, and can be used to improve real-time response, but it is no substitute for a real RTOS for deterministic performance.

You may be better off using the RPi and connecting it to a stand-alone microcontroller to perform the hard real-time processing.  There are a number of project examples connecting an Arduino to RPi for example.  The lower clock rate does not mean slower response since the processor can be dedicated to the task and will not non-deterministically switch to some other task for long periods.